# Correctly parse JSON

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to make a call to external API but I don't know how to correctly parse results. Here is the format of the response. I can correctly parse the Status, but Results is an array and nothing so far works:

```
{ 
   "Status":"OK",
   "Results":[ 
      { 
         "Header1":null,
         "Header2":null,
         "Header3":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is what I have tried and it doesn't work:

```
var res = HTTP.Get(url); <- up to here it works

var Response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(res.Response[0]);

var Header1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(res.Response[0].Header1);  <- doesn't work
var Header1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Response.Header1);  <- doesn't work
var Header1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(res.Header1);  <- doesn't work
```

And also this:

```
var res = HTTP.Get(url); <- up to here it works
var Response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(res.Response[0]);
var Header1 = Response.Header1;  <- doesn't work
var Header1 = res.Response[0].Header1;  <- doesn't work
```

Can you please suggest the best way to get all three headers from the Response array. Thank you

Comment: `var res = HTTP.Get(url); <- up to here it works` ==> after this line, can you put `console.log(res)` and show what you are getting?

Comment: In your example JSON you have a Results collection. In your code you reference Response as the collection name. Does Platform.Function.ParseJSON(res.Results[0].Header1) work?

Comment: Thank you Richard that was it. What a stupid mistake. Thank you